# Запись в БД через POST

Tags: php, mysql, sql

так работает:

`$userReg = "INSERT INTO`user`(`mail`) VALUES ('test')";`

а так нет:

`$userReg = "INSERT INTO`user`(`mail`) VALUES ('$_POST['label']')";`

Comment: ибо, надо: `$userReg = "INSERT INTOuser(mail) VALUES ('.$_POST['label'].')";`

Comment: Не надо. Сырой `$_POST[]`? Сначала экранировать хотя бы.

Comment: Матерь драконов!!1 Вы это серьёзно? В ответе должно быть ровно три буквы - `PDO`.

Answer (score 5):

Может так

```
$userReg = "INSERT INTO user(mail) VALUES ('{$_POST['label']}')";
```

и этот код открыт для SQL инъекций. Лучше всего использовать подготовленные запросы. Сейчас, если в `$_POST['label']` будет строка с одинарной кавычкой, то sql запрос будет невалидным.

Answer (score 3):

Никаких POST'ов в запросе! Даже в 90-е годы это было адским злом, а уж в 2017-ом тем более.

Если всё же сильно хочется воткнуть POST прямо в строку запроса, то значение надо экранировать, иначе получится уязвимость [SQL-inj](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0):

```
$userReg = "INSERT INTO user SET mail = '".addslashes($_POST['label'])."'";
```

Если к базе уже есть коннект, то корректнее экранировать так:

```
$userReg = "INSERT INTO user SET mail = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['label'])."'";
```

Оба варианта - плохие. Лучше не рассматривать их вообще и сразу шагнуть в 21й век в объятия [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php):

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO user SET mail = :mail');
$sth->execute([':mail' => $_POST['label']]);
```

И всё! Вы в безопасности!

[Пример подключения к базе](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php), [подготовка и выполнение запроса](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: Обожаю ответчиков, которые не могут сами определиться, что отвечать. Если какой-то вариант не рекомендуется, то зачем про него вообще писать

Answer (score 0):

Есть интересная особенность, вы не можете вставить в значение string ячейку массива без использования операторов. PHP сконвертирует только "чистую" переменную ($variable). $array['key'] не будет принято интерпретатором. Вообще, в любом случае подобная реализация некорректна из-за 2 причин.
Как сказали выше это небезопасно.
И второй момент, читаемость хромает в таком случае. Лучше все оформлять одним стилем, а именно

```
$var = "text " . $var2 . " text";
```

Comment: Почему не можете? Очень даже можем `"foo {$ar['key']} bar"`.

Answer (score -2):

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
$lable1 = isset($_POST['label']) ? strip_tags(trim($_POST['label'])) : '';

$lable1=(string)$lable1;
```

}
 Уточнить что только сторока будет в этой переменной.`

далее минимально подготавливаем  запрос.

```
$host='localhost';
$user='ivan';
$password='сам придумай';
$database='твоя база';
$port='80';
$link=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database,$port);
$userReg=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $userReg);
$query="INSERT INTO user (mail) VALUE (".$test.")";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Лопни мои глаза! Почему порт 80? И почему он строковый литерал?

Comment: И почему удаляются пробелы и тэги `strip_tags(trim(`? Я хоту лейбл с пробелами и тэгами.

Comment: Зачем тернарный оператор и эта проверка `isset(`, если выше уже всё и так проверяется `if (!empty(`?

Comment: затем что бы нотайсы не выбегали и не лопали твои глаза)